# Multi upload preview doesn't save all the images

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, parameters, simple-form, rails-activestorage

In my rails app I’m trying to create a multi upload preview function for my form. I’m using ActiveStorage.
But when I'm trying to upload multiple images it only saves one of the images. Actually it is the last image every time that is saved, all the other images are not.

I’m using devise for sign up, wicked wizard for multi step and cancancan for authorization. I'm also using rails admin.

**Appplication controller**

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:professions, :gender, :clinic_logo, :clinic_zip_code, clinic_images: []])
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:professions, :gender, :clinic_logo, :clinic_zip_code, clinic_images: []]) 
end
```

**Registration_steps controller**

```
def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:professions, :gender, :clinic_logo, :clinic_zip_code, clinic_images: []
)
end
```

**My form**

```
<%= form_for @user, url: wizard_path, method: :put do |f| %>

<div class="photos">

<% if @user.clinic_images.attached? %>
  <% @user.clinic_images.each do |image| %>

<div class="image-show">    
<%= image_tag(image.variant(resize: "100x100")) %>
   </div>
  <% end %>

<% end %>

<div class="image-upload"> 
<div class="overlay" id="oldDivImages"><div class="overlay-icon">+</div>
 <%= f.file_field :clinic_images, multiple: true, accept:'image/*', id: "gallery-photo-add" %> 
     </div>
<div class="overlay-text">Tilføj billede</div>

</div>
<div class="gallery"></div>

</div> 
<% end %>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    // Multiple images preview in browser
    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;

            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }

    };

    $('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
        imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What does your controller look like? Are you allowing the strong params? Are you setting the strong params for clinic_images as `clinic_images: []`?

Comment: You're right, I forgot to set the strong params like an array, but now I get a syntax error. I have updated the question with the params.

Comment: Any nested attributes like `clinic_images: []` needs to come at the end of the list. I'm not really sure why, but it never works for me unless params like that are all at the end of the list

Comment: Ok, now it doesn't throw me an error, but it only saves one image. Look at the updated question

Comment: Anyone knows how to fix it? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Sorry I'm at a loss :( The only thing I can think of, and I had to do this in an app with paperclip, was to create a method to set the images, where I looped through the image params and attached them that way